# Strange misprint on "Dragonball Z: The Legacy of Goku" cover

Tags: version-differences, dragon-ball-z-legacy

A friend on mine owns two versions of this game, *Dragon Ball Z: The Legacy of Goku* (in Italian *Il destino di Goku*):

[image]

The left one is the original version published by Atari. The right one is the newest version published by Infogrames.

The strange thing is that the left one has a sort of misprint, it appears that the Italian title was printed above a different one.
An `L` is clearly visible, it could be part of the French one, *L'Héritage de Goku* (there's an accent above the "D").

[image]
(Probably there's even a third one below)

Now here's my question:
Is this an actual misprint and therefore a rare copy?
Or does each Italian copy of that game has this "flaw"? If so, why was the title overwritten?

Comment: Anyway we can get a better picture?  Perhaps maybe one picture for each?  I can barely see the extra L on the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it can sound crazy, you are indeed right. This version of the game with the extra "L" at the beginning is really hiding the French title name of the game.

[image]

You can clearly see on your second picture the first L on the left, the end of the H above the second L, and the accent of the É above the D as you said yourself. You can also see the end of the shape of the E at the end of the first line.

[image]

Now, it seems to be a real flaw for the Atari version of the box. Looking around Google, all the pics I have seen from the Atari version do have this flaw.

[image]

(Another picture [here](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDc5Nw==/$(KGrHqVHJCME9BlWSe6YBPYFw51+ng~~60_12.JPG)) for instance).

Comment: The funny thing is that there's even a third one below, but I can't read it.